# How to access a button in the parent window from user control WPF C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, wpf-controls

In my `MainWindow`,

- I have a button `btnMainMenu`
- I have a user control `NavigationWindow`

from the user control, I want to change the visibility of the `btnMainMenu` form the `MainWindow`. I have tried most of the steps suggested in other posts but none of them seems to work for me.

I tried this line of code but got error.

```
System.Windows.Controls.Button btn = (this.Parent as MainWindow).Controls["btnMainMenu"] as Button;
```

Comment: Provide an event in user control to which main window can subscribe.

Comment: could you please ellaborate @Sinatr ?

Comment: Go to user control source. Add `SomethingHappens` [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/event) there with custom `EventArgs` if needed (e.g. `bool` parameter). In main window subscribe to this event where you create instance of user control. In event handler toggle button visibility.

Comment: Btw, before it's too late take a look into MVVM. It help abstract the logic and many things are much easier to achieve. With it you just need bool property somewhere (e.g. dependency property in custom control view) to bind button visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to please go through some design patterns.
This is not supposed to be a recommended way to get an object and changed the visibility.

Have a view and a view model make some dependency and change some property of view model.

Just for your learning, I can tell you one of the way but definitely would not recommend it in your product.

You can use recursion on the child controls of the parent control till you find out the button control you need.